# Private Git server is invisible or unreachable

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, permissions, public-key

1. On Ubuntu machine I created a repo' as follows

   `netcomo@netcomoserver:/opt/git/groupware.git$ ll
    Total 12
   drwxr-xr-x 3 git git 4096  April 26 16:18 ./
   drwxr-xr-x 3 git git 4096  April 26 13:50 ../
   drwxr-xr-x 7 git git 4096  April 26 16:18 .git/
   netcomo@netcomoserver:/opt/git/groupware.git$`
2. On Windows 7 where I want to clone the repo' I'm having below error.
   What could be the reason? (as you can see the repo' server is reachable)
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your git server is reachable.
You are using SSH to access the GIT repo. In that case you need to create an SSH key.

If you doing so, store your public key

```
.ssh/authorized_keys
```

on your Ubuntu maschine.

On Windows you can create SSH keys using Putty [http://www.putty.org](http://www.putty.org/)/

Answer (score 0):

I should have checked a few things as follows:

1. To copy public key from a client machine to the server using "ssh-copy-id" command (example is shown below), I need to change a option of sshd_config file to 'yes' on the server computer.
   Command:

   $ ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_rsa netcomo@netcomoserver

   $ sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

   PasswordAuthentication yes
2. After copying the public key to the server, the 'yes' changed above needs to be changed back to 'no'
3. For your reference, if you need to access multiple server accounts, you have to copy the same public key for each different accounts, see examples that follow.

   $ ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_rsa netcomo@netcomoserver

   $ ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_rsa netcomo2@netcomoserver

.